# Display win/lose picture after gameState changes (SFML Minesweeper)

Tags: c++, sfml, minesweeper

So I wrote minesweeper game and made GUI with SFML, just have a problem with displaying picture of win/lose when player finishes the game or loses it. Game states are set well and they trigger at right moments, the problem is that pictures I want to display I think are too big and in the window, I can see only their background (like top left corner of the picture). Is there a way to scale the picture to the window and display it fully in the window?

Constructor:

```
minesweeperBoard* board;
sf::Texture t;

MSSFMLView::MSSFMLView(minesweeperBoard& board) {
    this->board = &board;
    t.loadFromFile("src/images/tiles.jpg");
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(32*this->board->getBoardWidth(), 32*this->board->getBoardHeight()), "Minesweeper");
}
```

Gamestate if trigger in a game loop:

```
    if(board->state == GameState::FINISHED_WIN){
        t.loadFromFile("src/images/win.jpg");
        sf::Sprite s(t);
        s.scale(32*this->board->getBoardWidth(),32*this->board->getBoardHeight());
        window.draw(s);
        Sleep(1000);
        window.clear();
    }else if(board->state == GameState::FINISHED_LOSS){
        t.loadFromFile("src/images/lose.jpg");
        sf::Sprite s(t);
        s.scale(32*this->board->getBoardWidth(),32*this->board->getBoardHeight());
        window.draw(s);
        Sleep(1000);
        window.clear();
    }
```

Those are the pictures I use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hOED.jpg
256x256 size

Answer (score 0):

When you call s.scale(32*this->board->getBoardWidth(),32*this->board->getBoardHeight());
what you are doing is increasing the size of the image by an amount in the x and y direction, in this case 32 times the board size. This will make the image too large to fit onto the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the [scale](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#aaec50b46b3f41b054763304d1e727471) function changes the size of a sf::Sprite by **multiplying it**, not by setting it.
So if you want to change the size of an image to fit your board, don't use

```cpp
s.scale(32*this->board->getBoardWidth(),32*this->board->getBoardHeight());
```

because that is multiplying the size of the image, making it huge. Instead, scale it by the desired size divided by the actual size:

```cpp
float desiredW = 32*this->board->getBoardWidth();
float desiredH = 32*this->board->getBoardHeight();
float currentW = s.getGlobalBounds().width;
float currentH = s.getGlobalBounds().height;
s.scale(desiredW / currentW, desiredH / currentH);
```